# Dialogflow dynamic enity issue

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am trying to create an Actions on Google app using Dialogflow (api.ai). I need to get the train status. So my entity will be train number or train name. There is a lot of train names. So I can't add the entity values manually. How can i add entity values dynamically to the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add large sets of values and synonyms either JSON or CVS formatted by:

1. Directly pasting them in the **Entity raw mode** JSON or CSV fields.
   [image: raw mode switch]
2. Uploading a JSON or CSV formatted file entity.
   [image: Upload entity]
3. Make POST calls to the Dialogflow API. See more [here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/entities#post_entities).

While you can use the **Allow automated expansion** checkbox in the entity to take what the user says as an entity value even though it wasn't defined I would advice against it as it will require a large amount of examples (entity values) for training to be able to match relevantly. Find more [here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities#allow_automated_expansion).